# create nested groups of nodes in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to use networkx to create groups within groups, etc of nodes.

For instance I have nodes [1,2,3,4,5,6] currently no sub groups.  I want it to end up being like this
[1,2,[[3,4],[5,6]]

Currently I am just doing a for loop with some data and adding the nodes to the graph like this.

```
    self.G = nx.Graph()
    for s in self.tabledata:
        self.G.add_node(s[0])
        self.G.__dict__['_node'][s[0]]['label'] = '{0}'.format(s[0])
    nx.write_graphml(self.G, '/filename')
```

where self.tabledata contains the following values [1234,2345,3456,4567,5678,6789]

I want to move 3 and 4 to be in a group 'A' together, 5 and 6 to be in group 'B' together and groups A and B to be in group 'C' along with nodes 1, and 2.

so as far as groups are concerned you have this [C[A,B]]

Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the values stored in `self.tabledata` ?

Comment: added what self.tabledata contains

Comment: are the group sequence same for all the values like, will it always be ` [C[A,B]]` ?

Comment: not necessariily, just want to be able to put things into subgroups.